# Retrieve all the not nullable fileds that don't have a default value

Tags: sql, oracle

The title says it all. How to get the not nullable columns' names that don't have a default value in PL/SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean in Oracle SQL? Your question doesn't seem to be about PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the columns `nullable` and `data_default` of [`dba_tab_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4146.htm), [`all_tab_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) or [`user_tab_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm) depending on what objects you want the columns from and what rights you have. `dba_tab_columns` shows the columns of all tables, views etc. `all_tab_columns` of all you can access and `user_tab_columns` of all you own. If a column is not nullable `nullable = 'N'`, if there's no default `data_default IS NULL`.

For example:

```
SELECT *
       FROM user_tab_columns
       WHERE nullable = 'N'
             AND data_default IS NULL;
```